# Get total comments, likes, and shares from Facebook - prints only zeros

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

I want to get for example total comments, but it only prints zeros (0) from the link below:

https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=SELECT+share_count%2C+like_count%2C+comment_count%2C+total_count+FROM+link_stat+WHERE+url%3D%22http://www.facebook.com/erikedgrensgalleri%22

If I change `erikedgrensgalleri` to `cocacola` it works perfectly! Why can't I get total comments and more from my Facebook page? I have 7 likes and several comments already there!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you parse out the FQL from your URL?

Comment: SELECT share_count like_count,+comment_count, total_count FROM link_stat WHERE url="http://www.facebook.com/erikedgrensgalleri"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They don't start doing metrics on Facebook pages until you have 30 number of fans and over. I'm pretty sure that's why, but not positive. I also can't see my facebook page counts. For more info & documentation (for what it's worth): http://developers.facebook.com/docs/insights/

Comment: Thanks! Your answer is correct. I found this at the bottom of the page you linked to: "Yes. For user privacy reasons, Insights are only provided to Pages with greater than 30 users who like that Page."